# Is there a way to put a regular link in this code

Tags: hyperlink

Is there a way to make some of these use a regular link and still show up? The selfUrl is adding something in front that I don't need for a couple of the links.

```
$menu_opts = array(array('Events',selfUrl(array('action' => 'm_events'))),
                               array('Concert',selfUrl(array('action' => 'Adverts-a-left1'))),
                               array('Specials',selfUrl(array('action' => 'm_events','category'=>8))),
                               array('Coupons',selfUrl(array('action' => 'm_coupons'))),
                               array('Portals',selfUrl(array('action' => 'm_portals'))),
                               array('Videos',selfUrl(array('action' => 'm_videos'))),
                               array('Sports',selfUrl(array('action' => 'page','id' => 27))),
                               array('Social',selfUrl(array('action' => 'm_social'))),
                               array('Weather',selfUrl(array('action' => 'm_weather'))),
                               array('About',selfUrl(array('action' => 'mobile','id' => '50')))
```

I need to add some regular links in here that want pull the index.php?action= in front of them from the selfurl. Example below of the link only I need to pull

```
array('Concert',selfUrl(array('action' => 'https://www.mysight.com/Adverts-a-left1/'))),
```

Comment: What do mean with regular link? this is a list of arrays. Looks a bit like PHP. Are you using some framework? What are you doing with `$menu_opts`?